# Conditional compilation within a macro?

Tags: macros

I'm trying to define an environment that is conditionally complied in lualatex. The two solutions I've tried are the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{test}{\ifx\X y \\ }{\else \\ \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
This should not be seen without the varible X set to y.
\end{test}

this should always be seen.

\end{document}
```

The following also does not work:

```
\newenvironment{test}{\ifdef{\something}{ }{ }{}}
```

Nor does:

```
\newenvironment{text}{\ifdef \\ }{\else \\ \fi}
```

Whereas all of the above *do work* in both pdftex and lualatex if I manually replace the "\begin{test}" and "\end{test}" in my code with their definitions.

What gives? Does LaTeX not let you use \ifdef and similar constructs within user-defined environments/definitions? Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use the `comment` package to do something like that. Your approach doesn't work because when TeX processes a conditional it will look for an "explicit" `\else` or `\fi`, which are not there. For the `\else` and `\fi` to appear you'd have to expand the `\end{test}` before.

Comment: Try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/6TU9HS4d). Comment/uncomment the `\def\X{y}` component.